# How can I bindInterceptor in Google Guice when the Interceptor does not have a default constructor?

Tags: java, java-8, guice

I have the following Guice module:

```java
public class GuiceModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {}

    @Provides
    ClassA classA() {
        return new ClassA();
    }

    @Provides
    ClassB classB(ClassA classA) {
        ClassB classB = new ClassB(classA);
        classB.configure(123)
        classB.modify(456);
    }

    @Provides
    ClassC classC(ClassB classB) {
        return new ClassC(classB);
    }
}
```

I need to add the following `bindInterceptor`

```java
bindInterceptor(
    inSubpackage("my.sub.package"),
    annotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class),
    classC);
```

I can only call `bindInterceptor` from the `configure()` method, based on Line 140 of [this file](http://www.howsoftworks.net/guice-PrivateModule).

What other options do I have besides not using `@Provides` methods and instead doing everything in the `configure` method?

**Note:** I don't own ClassA, ClassB, or ClassC. They all come from a third party package.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to [inject your interceptors](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AOP#injecting-interceptors).

You have to write your injectors slightly differently and not use the constructor injection.

```
class ClassC {
  @Inject
  ClassB classB;                                         // Write all dependencies like this.
  @Inject
  void setClassB(ClassB classB) { this.classB = classB } // Or like this

  ClassC() { } // Write any constructor that you can actually instanciate manually
}
```

Then in your `configure` method:

```
ClassC classC = new ClassC();
requestInjection(classC);
bindInterceptor(inSubpackage("foo"), annotatedWith(Bar.class), classC);
```

---

Since you don't have access to the interceptor code, write your own that encapsulate the one you want:

```
class MyInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
  ClassC delegate;
  
  @Inject
  void inject(ClassB classB) { // If more dependencies are required, you can add them as parameter here, it'll just work. Don't add a setter per dependency.
    delegate = new ClassC(classB);
  }
  
  @Override
  public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    return delegate.invoke(invocation);
  }
}
```

Now use `MyInterceptor` instead of `ClassC` in your configure method:

```
MyInterceptor interceptor = new MyInterceptor();
requestInjection(interceptor);
bindInterceptor(inSubpackage("foo"), annotatedWith(Bar.class), interceptor);
```

Comment: Hi, this looks like a great answer. Unfortunately, I forgot to mention that I don't own any of the classes, so I can't modify their constructors.

Comment: @David I updated my answer with your comments in mind.